# Passing information from child state to parent state in angular-ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am building an angular-app with ui-router where I have a parent view and a child view.

```
routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/views/home/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })
        .state('new-assignment', {
            url: '/new-assignment',
            templateUrl: 'new-assignment.html',
            controller: 'AssignmentController'
        })
            .state('new-assignment.new-client', {
                url: '/new-client',
                templateUrl: 'new-client.html',
                controller: 'ClientController'
            })
    ;

});
```

The child view is used (among other things) to create a new client.
So, by clicking on 'create new client' in the main view. The state is change to 'new-assignment.new-client', and the side view is shown.

When the client is created I want to transition back to the parent view 'new-assignment' and pass along information with what client that have just been created.

The parent view could still have data in its own form (for creating assignment) and should naturally not be touched.

I can detect a change by '$stateChangeSuccess' event:

```
routerApp.controller('AssignmentController', function($scope, Assignment, Client, $log) {
    $scope.clients = Client.clients;
    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        $log.log(fromState.name + ' -> ' + toState.name);
        $log.log('toParams ');
        $log.log(toParams);
        $log.log('fromParams ');
        $log.log(fromParams);
    });
});
```

I have tried to pass info through

```
$state.go('^', data);
```

but without success...

But I don't understand how to pass data to the parent view. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Child view scope inherits from the scope of the parent view. So just define `$scope.clients[]` array in the `AssignmentController`. Then add the new client to that array in the `ClientController`.

[Take a look at this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9cIbOSUrSrARKSiOF6R7) to see how the nested view scopes get access to their parent view scope.

Comment: I see your point but I'm not fond of changing stuff in 'others' scope. It could very easy become messy, especially since this will update specific input elements etc. I decided to use events to inform about updates. See my answer.
Thanks for your input @david004

Comment: You seriously think that is less messy? The framework has inheritance for a reason.

Comment: The child state view scope does not inherits from the scope of the parent state view unless the child state view is nested in the parent state view. One example where the views are not nested is modals.

Comment: This is cool feature! Events $emit is bad idea. The more items you want to override, the more you need this way.

Answer (score 3):

Rudely I will answer my own question.

I decided to go with event messaging:

```
app.controller('ClientController', function ($scope, $state, ClientService) {

    $scope.save = function (newClientData) {
        var ret = ClientService.create(newClientData);
        if (ret) {
            // Pass newly created object to parent view.
            $scope.$emit('clientCreated', newClientData);
            // Then go to that state (closing child view)
            $log.log($state);
            if ($state.current.name === 'new-client')
                return $state.go('home');
            $state.go('^');
        }
    };
});

app.controller('AssignmentController', function ($scope, Assignment, ClientService) {
    $scope.clients = ClientService.clients;

    $scope.$on('clientCreated', function (e, data) {
        $scope.clientSelected(data);
    });

    $scope.clientSelected = function (client) {
        $log.log(client);
        $scope.data.client = client;
        $scope.data.clientName = client.name;
        $scope.data.clientId = client.id;
    }
});
```

This code is linked to the code in my question!

Comment: It's a bad idea to use events, try not to put them in you app because you may end up with a terrible performance. 
Events trigger every scope while looking for the ".on required event handler".

Answer (score 0):

yes, various ideas.

You can send the data information using query parameters. Converting your data to JSON and sending like this "$state.go('^', data)" and defining your state url with "new-assignmentww/?data".

If data is assigned, you can get information and convert to object again.

Other, you can access the parent state using "$state.$parent" and assign the value in the controller, then you can call the "$state.go('^')".

You can also create a callback function in controller of the parent state and call in the controller of the children state.